# Reference for Curvature operator

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. The curvature operator on $\Lambda^2(TM)$ is defined on decomposable bivectors by
$$g(\mathfrak{R}(X \wedge Y), V \wedge W) = R(X,Y,W,V)$$

where $g$ is given by the formula $g(X\wedge Y,Z\wedge W):=g(X,Z)g(Y,W)-g(X,W)g(Y,Z)$ and is extended by linearity to all of $\Lambda^2(TM)$. I want to know more about curvature operator and important theorems and open questions about it. Is there some good reference (Book) on this topic? If the answer is 'NO' can you introduce some good paper?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about the book/paper you found this definition in?

Comment: Here: http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1978_4_11_1_71_0.pdf Curvature operators: pinching estimates and geometric examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at *Einstein Manifolds* by Besse, chapter $1$, section $H$ (it might help to also read section $G$). In particular, corollary $1.129$ tells you about the relationship between the curvature operator and Einstein in dimension four.

Comment: I can't find the definition of curvature operator  in this book?

Comment: It is first defined in $1.86$ (page $42$ in my copy).

Comment: Ok. I find it. but is corollary 1.129 about it?

Comment: Yes. In that corollary $R$ denotes the curvature operator (see the text before the corollary where they regard $R \in S^2\bigwedge^2E$ as a linear map $\bigwedge^2E \to \bigwedge^2E$).